# Comparisons in Bash script ran from Azure Pipeline always return false

Tags: bash, azure-pipelines, comparison

I am running a script where I need to compare two strings. It runs correctly locally, but if I runin through an Azure-Pipeline in Azure DevOPs, the script runs but my if statements always go through the else part.

For example the script in this file:

```
#############################################
teststr="test"
echo $teststr
if [[ $teststr == "test" ]]; then
      echo "true"
else
      echo "false"
fi
    
if [[ $teststr != "test" ]]; then
      echo "true"
else
      echo "false"
fi
#############################################
```

Should output

```
test
true
false
```

It does when I run it in command line
But when ran in an azure pipeline like this:

```
az vm run-command invoke --command-id RunShellScript --name MyVM -g Takeoffs --scripts "cd /home/user/workdir/ && 
    ./script.sh"
```

it outputs

```
test
false
false
```

How can I get it to compare the strings correctly?

I tried comparing different strings, adding quotes, I tried the -eq and -ne operators.
But since it works in command line, I figure the syntax is correct, and maybe there is an environment issue?

Comment: Is azure actually running the script with bash? The most likely way to get your stated output is to run a shell that doesn't support `[[`, I can replicate in dash for example. Try adding a shebang to the script (`#!/bin/bash`) and/or invoking bash directly - `bash ./script.sh` versus simply `./script.sh`

Comment: Thank you! bash ./script.sh seems to behave correctly now!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that it was not in fact run with bash.
Here is the original answer:

Is azure actually running the script with bash? The most likely way to get your stated output is to run a shell that doesn't support [[, I can replicate in dash for example. Try adding a shebang to the script (#!/bin/bash) and/or invoking bash directly - bash ./script.sh versus simply ./script.sh